# TypeScript: import and export "at the same time"

Tags: typescript, types, module

Is there a way of doing an import and an export of the same named variable, at the same time, in the same TypeScript file?

For instance, the following situation:

```
import { State as UIState } from './ui'
import { State as ConnectionState } from './connection'

export { State as UIState } from './ui'
export { State as ConnectionState } from './connection'

export type State = {
    ui: UIState
    connection: ConnectionState
}
```

To reduce writing cost, I would like to be able to write something like that:

```
export import { State as UIState } from './ui'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm looking for the same feature

Answer (score 9):

Creating a "index.ts" file (or foo.ts) reduced the repetitive import/export. (I am not sure if this is a good solution)

```
export * from './product-form.component'
export * from './product-list.component'
```

Angular module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import * as c from './index';
export * from './index'

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ 
        c.ProductListComponent,
        c.ProductFormComponent, 
    ]
  })
  export class ProductModule { }
```

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way of doing an import and an export of a the same named variable, at the same time, in the same TypeScript file

No. There is no *JS module* syntax for that.

Comment: Is the question not asking for [barrel](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/barrel.html) exports?

Comment: Yes, it is creating a barrel export, however the question is not about how to do a barrel. Each of the imports mentioned are called `State` and therefore need to be renamed. The question is about how to do  `import + export + rename` in a single statement. There isn't a syntax for that 

Comment: This answer simply isn't true and isn't wrong, but misleading. You can do `export { default as someNamed } from './file'`  check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73830512/18387350

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript Modules (Es modules) if you want to
`export import something from './somewhere'` you can do it through the following syntax:

```js
export { default } from './somewhere'
```

if you want to `export import { someNamed } from './somewhere'` you can do it through the following syntax:

```js
export { someNamed } from './somewhere'
```

---

- plus, if you want to make them export **as** a named export instead of a default export you can do them as follows instead:

```js
// # theFile.js
export { default as newNamed1} from './somewhere'
export { someNamed as newNamed2 } from './somewhere'
```

Now when you import these from another file, you import them as the following instead:

```js
import { newNamed1, newNamed2 } from './theFile.js'
```

Comment: i think author wants to use exported things in the same file. but dont want to write same things (for example the path) twice.